# Mysql Update query issue using json_encode in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

When i update data using php mysql, got some issue, my code php code are here

```
$query = "UPDATE `wp_experience` SET 
                     `exp_from` ='". $exp_from."' ,
                     `exp_to` = '". $exp_to."' ,
                     `exp_title` = '". json_encode($exp_title)."',
                     `exp_desc` = '". json_encode($exp_desc)."' ,                               
                     `exp_cat` = '". $exp_cat."'                                
                     WHERE `id` =".$oldid;
```

it will produce data like,

> UPDATE `wp_experience` SET `exp_from` ='2016-01-22 00:00:00' , `exp_to` = '2002-11-14 00:00:00' , `exp_title` = '{"en":" PSA Peugeot Citroën Automobiles, Mulhouse (F-68)","fr":"Technical Directué - FRENCH","de":"Responsable d'unité de maintenance"}', `exp_desc` = '{"en":"
>   Test</p>","fr":"
>   Test</p>","de":"
>   H</p>"}' , `exp_cat` = '18' WHERE `id` =28

i got this issue,

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'unité de maintenance"}', `exp_desc` = '{"en":"
>   Test</p>","fr":"
>   Test</p' at line 1

How to fix this issue??

Comment: `Responsable d'unité` string breaks your query. use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` as much as you can in order to avoid such problems.

Comment: Please use prepared statements!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of your embedded strings breaks your query, so either use `mysqli_real_escape_string()` or prepared SQL statements:

```
$query = "
    UPDATE 
        wp_experience 
    SET 
        exp_from    = '" . $exp_from . "' ,  
        exp_to      = '" . $exp_to . "' , 
        exp_title   = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, json_encode($exp_title)) . "',  
        exp_desc    = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, json_encode($exp_desc)) . "' ,
        exp_cat     = '" . mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $exp_cat) . "'
    WHERE 
        id = " . $oldid;
```